# How to make a global error handler in Redux and override it when needed?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, redux

Imagine a situation of handling form submit which can return different errors: 400, 401, 500.
When 400 is returned, I want to show a message in top of the form (override the default behavior). 
For other (unhandled) error codes, the default (global) error handler should be invoked (which shows notification toast). Just don't want to duplicate this code for every single action

I dispatch async actions using redux-thunk middleware

```
// Pseudo code
const action = (dispatch) => {

    const onSuccess = (result) => dispatch({type: 'OPERATION_SUCCESS', payload: result});
    const onError = (error) => dispatch({type: 'OPERATION_ERROR', error: true, payload: error});

    return promise.then(onSuccess, onError);

};
dispatch(action);
```

I can create a reducer which handles all **{error: true}** actions and show some popup-notification (probably without using redux state, directly invoking some toast.show() method)
But how to determine if this special error was already handled by some other reducer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By the time an action reaches a reducer, it is a *fact*. It reflects something that has already happened. There is no sense in asking “has other reducer handled this action?” because reducers are supposed to be passive and, in general sense, unaware of each other’s existence. They should strive to be independent, where possible.

There is no one “true” way to accomplish what you wanted, but since you already use the convention of treating any object with an `error` property as a global error, you might as well introduce another convention like “if the action has a `suppressGlobalErrorNotification` flag then the global error reducer should not care about it”.

```
// utilities

function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response
  } else {
    const error = new Error(response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json()
}

export function post(url, data) {
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)  
  }
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
}

// action creators

import { post } from './utils'

export function submitForm(data) {
  return dispatch => post('/myform', data).then(
    response => dispatch({
      type: 'SUBMIT_FORM_SUCCESS',
      payload: response
    }),
    error => dispatch({
      type: 'SUBMIT_FORM_FAILURE',
      error: error,
      suppressGlobalErrorNotification: (
        error.response &&
        error.response.status === 400
      )
    })
  )
}

// reducers

export function error(state = null, action) {
  if (!action.error || action.suppressGlobalErrorNotification) {
    return state
  }
  if (action.type === 'RESET_ERROR') {
    return null
  }
  return action.error
}


export function form(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'SUBMIT_FORM_FAILURE':
    return Object.assign({}, state, { isFormError: true })
  // ...
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong @DanAbramov, but in the `error` reducer function, doesn't it need to check for `RESET_ERROR` first? I just tried this myself and when you try and reset the error message nothing happens. I think this is because the first `if` condition holds true because `action.error` is of course undefined when resetting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Same things for me, I didn't find any working solution than can handle it.
@Dan Abramov showed the example but the issue here is when you have tens of forms things becomes more complicated. Each time you need to handle same things, duplicate code starts to be annoying. 
For example:

```
form => client validation => CLIENT_VALIDATION_ERROR => reducer

                       FETCH_STARTED
form => form submit => SERVER_SIDE_SUCCESS  => reducers
                       SERVER_SIDE_ERROR
```

There can be an exception where we need to handle such behaviour manually but in most cases it's not.

Comment: If you have duplicate code, extract it in a function.

Comment: True, but there should be some type of generator on action and reducer side, to skip all aux constant creation and handlers. It hides the real implementation from developer and becomes a magic (some developers might don't like it)

Comment: It’s hard to discuss without any specific example. I don’t see how the approach I suggested above results in duplication yet. Can you show a gist?

Comment: Here is my gist: https://gist.github.com/smolyakoff/afbc5bcb9c2bee7cc407. I wanted to use a set of conventional helpers to make the components deal mostly with rendering and move error-handling logic out of them.

Comment: @DanAbramov I don't see how your code can be applied to 3,4,5 forms. 1 action constant = 1 reducer, that's not optimization. I still don't know how to do it easily with redux but next is my realisation with atljs https://gist.github.com/2j2e/ed88c8767c69f06586b0

Comment: @2j2e I don’t understand your question. "1 action constant = 1 reducer" <--- why? This is not what I recommend. Maybe you can create a separate question showing a specific problem and I could try to answer that.

Comment: @KonstantinSmolyakov That’s a bit too involved for me to answer here. Can you create a new question showing the *duplication* you are referring to, rather than your solution to it. I could try to help you answer that.